# Why doesn't UIkeyboard animate when called from a Custom Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a subclass of a UItableViewCell

When a user touches a CELL, I call reload, like this:

```
[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

// This is where magic happens...
[_tableView beginUpdates];
[_tableView endUpdates];
```

And a new cell takes shows up. This new cell becomes the first responder for the _workName UITextField, like this:

```
@implementation TWMainViewPlusExpandedCell

- (void) awakeFromNib
{        
    [_workName becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

The keyboard shows up, but without animation. It's instant! There seems to be no animation whatsoever!

However, when I resign the keyboard, by calling resignFirstResponder, it resigns with animation, as expected.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your cell becomes responder and brings up keyboard before or during the tableview animation caused by reload.
Try

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{        
    [_workName performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) onThread:[NSThread getMainThread] withObject:nil withDelay:0.1];

}
```

I question why you are reloading the table just to select a cell.

Comment: I'm realoading the table because the touch makes a new cell appear in place of the old one. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: I did it with a delay, as you suggested, and it fixed things up. Isn't there a better way of doing this? On an older iPhone, if executions takes a little more time, the animation stutturs.

Comment: The problem is, as you see, you are relying on the timing which can't really be certain. The delay is kind of a workaround hack. If you get the results you want, why spend more time.

Comment: I don't know the particulars of what you are trying to accomplish, but I assume you are making the cell editable and modifying the layout. That code should really stay with your custom cell. That way you can control the animation and become first responder on completion. In that way you can assure the sequence of events.

Comment: Not editable, just loading a new one, but that does make a lot of sense. Now that I come to think of it, I don't really think I need 2 cells... Thank you for your insight Sir.